# Can Crumbs be used with Panels?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite, breadcrumbs

I'm building a site with Panels (and Panels Everywhere, with a custom theme based on Precision) and trying to customize the breadcrumbs for particular nodes based on their content type.

The Crumbs module looks like it does what I need, and I've been able to make it work perfectly on a test site in Garland, but as soon as I switch to using Panels, the Crumbs breadcrumbs aren't being used.

Specifically, it looks like the "Breadcrumb" Page Element Content provided by ctools doesn't use the Crumbs breadcrumb trail. Somehow crumbs_preprocess_page is being completely suppressed.

Can these two modules be made to work together? I don't see any open issues for Crumbs, or any comments on the troubleshooting page at http://drupal.org/node/1008658, so I have to think that *someone* has made this work.

(Drupal 7.18, Panels 1.2, CTools 3.3, and Crumbs 1.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crumbs provides a "Breadcrumb (Crumbs)" block that you should be able to use.

Comment: That's definitely interesting.. I will take a look for that; I though that I had checked all of the categories in the 'Add Content' dialog, but perhaps I managed to overlook it. Is this a new (dev?) feature, or should it exist in 7.x-1.8?

Comment: Thanks Bojan -- that worked perfectly (once I remembered to clear cache :) ).

Comment: Looks like this was committed in November, but didn't make the 1.8 release, so it's only in 7.x-1.x-dev for now. http://drupal.org/node/1822956 is the relevant issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it was in the latest release.
I guess it's time for a new one.

Comment: It is in the 1.9 release.
Some of the previous releases were "hotfix", so they didn't include new features.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Crumbs, but there is [Panels Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/panels_breadcrumbs).  It lets you set breadcrumbs for each panel page within panels configuration, and your breadcrumbs can be exported with [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features).

Comment: Panels Breadcrumbs doesn't seem to provide any way to use a node's position in a menu to construct breadcrumbs, as far as I can tell, which I need for certain (but not all) content types. Otherwise, I'd be using it, since it definitely does work with Panels Everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module instead?  I've used it successfully with Panels without incident.

From the project page:

> "Many new features have been added including support for Views,
>   **Panels**, Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for
>   module pages and theme templates. These are implemented using
>   optional, independent submodules that depend on the main Custom
>   Breadcrumbs module."

Further, Custom Breadcrumbs has more than 30,000 installations, while Crumbs only has about 4,000, so you may find that issues are better documented as well.

For further reference: [Comparison of breadcrumb-related modules](http://drupal.org/node/533448)

Comment: FYI:  Custom Breadcrumbs is [likely to be deprecated](http://drupal.org/node/1823080) in favour of [Path Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) :)

Comment: Crumbs is the only regularly maintained and well written breadcrumb module in Drupal (apologies if you maintain one I haven't seen yet).

Custom Breadcrumbs is a disaster.

(Disclaimer: I have commit access to Crumbs due to contributing to it after having to remove Custom Breadcrumbs from Kickstart v2)

Also note that I haven't tried the mentioned Path Breadcrumbs.